# group background doesn't change in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to change group color but background attribute `android:background="#666"` did not change the color.
How can i add background color for group in constraint layout?
if i cannot what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

A group is a construct in `ConstraintLayout` that helps to control the visibility of each view within the group.

From the [`Group docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group):

> This class controls the visibility of a set of referenced widgets. Widgets are referenced by being added to a comma separated list of ids...

If you want to change an attribute for each view within a group other than visibility, you will have to get the id of each view and work from there. Use [getReferencedIds()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group.html#getReferencedIds()) to do this.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46745968/6287910) on how to do this.