# How to set the size of buttons in a chain for different layouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I would like to add 3 buttons into my Android ConstraintLayout such that they are spanned horizontally. I thought that this can be done by using chains. So I made a chain out of them and then expanded their view (by marking them --> Right Click --> Organize --> Expand Horizontally). However this just expands them for one specific device. When switching to another device the buttons don't look correct any more. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rigthInnerConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="425dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2"
            android:layout_width="425dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="Button 2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_3"
            android:layout_width="426dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="Button_3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For the height I use scalable I use scalable size units (https://github.com/intuit/sdp) but for the width of the buttons dp values are assigned by Android Studio (after the expanding). I think that this is the problem. These dp values are hard coded. This means when changing the device the values are still the same which leads to the not correct look. My question is how can I arrange the 3 buttons in a chain (or whatever) such that they span over a whole row horizontally for any device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*These dp values are hard coded. This means when changing the device the values are still the same which leads to the not correct look* - this is correct.

### How to fix

If you will replace `android:layout_width="426dp"` on your buttons with `android:layout_width="0dp"`.
your buttons will now resect the constraints and now every button will take `33.3%` of the screen width.

You can change the width that every button will take by adding `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.x"` to your button (it will only work if your view will have `android:layout_width="0dp"` as well), now your button will take x% of the screen width.

### Example

For a 3 buttons places In a row **but** the center button will take 50% of the screen size you can use it like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     android:id="@+id/rigthInnerConstraintLayout"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:background="@color/white"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
     app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"

     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/outerConstraintLayout"
     app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_1"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:text="Button 1"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_2"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:text="Button 2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button_3"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_1"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button_3"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:text="Button_3"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_2"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And it will look like this:

[image]

Without `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"` every button will take equal space and it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tamir for your answe. Basically I came up with another solution for this problem. I just inserted a linear layout into the constraintLayout and then added the 3 buttons into the linear layout. But your solution is also good. I upvoted it.

Comment: Your solution will make your app slower, the point of constaintLayout is to prevent this nesting layout. when you don't have nested layouts your app (for most cases) will run faster, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813792/nested-constraint-layout-is-it-a-bad-practice-or-not/53814219) for more info

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tamir. I will stick to my solution with the nested layout (because I have implement it for many fragments). I will check it then later whether the app reacts slowly or not. Honestly I can't imagine that this will make a cruical difference. Further, I have used this construction on many other occassions and so far I have not experienced any difficulties. However, I will check later whether there is in fact a significant difference regarding the runtime as you pointed out.

Comment: Anyways I accepted your answer as it solves the problem. Thanks for your effort. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button width **0dp** of all button and see the magic :)

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```